# German special chars displayed incorrectly

Tags: django, postgresql

We're using Django 1.5 and Postgres 9.1. The database encoding is UTF-8. The website encoding is UTF-8. Some non-ascii chars - including French *é* - are displayed correctly.

The only issue is the German umlauts and special chars. Examples of the wrong chars:

Ã¼ber

ausgewÃ¤hlte

FlÃ¼ge

If I inspect the raw Postgres output using *select blabla from tablename*, then it looks badly again:

... R\xfcckverg\xfctung...

Looks like Django puts raw unicode values into the database instead of converting them to the appropriate chars.

*psql* **\l** output:

```
                                  List of databases
       Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
    -----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
     my_database  | postgres | UTF8     | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |

```

*locale* server output:

```

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your environment not being configured as UTF-8?

Comment: Select the raw output *using what*? What's the output of the `locale` command on the server? What's the output of `\l databasename` in `psql`?

Comment: (BTW, I suspect not everything is as utf-8 as you think it is and you're using some 1-byte encoding that's getting munged)

Comment: @RaphaelLaurent I think it's UTF8 since any other data (French special chars, for example) is correct.

Comment: @CraigRinger I've edited the post, please see the psql and locale outputs